# Martin Odersky : Working hard to keep it simple

Tags: scala, asynchronous, logic

I was watching the talk given by Martin Odersky as recommended by himself in the coursera scala course and I am quite curious about one aspect of it

```
var x = 0
async { x = x + 1 }
async { x = x * 2 }
```

So I get that it can give 2 if if the first statement gets executed first and then the second one:

```
x = 0;
x = x + 1;
x = x * 2; // this will be x = 2
```

I get how it can give 1 :

```
x = 0;
x = x * 2;
x = x + 1 // this will be x = 1
```

However how can it result 0? Is it possible that the statement don't execute at all?

Sorry for such an easy question but I'm really stuck at it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to think about *interleaved* execution. Remember that the CPU needs to read the value of `x` before it can work on it. So imagine the following:

1. Thread 1 reads `x` (reading 0)
2. Thread 2 reads `x` (reading 0)
3. Thread 1 writes `x + 1` (writing 1)
4. Thread 2 writes `x * 2` (writing 0)

Comment: Interleaved execution will only allow of the threads to execute. If it's the first one it will result 0. Is this it?

Comment: No - the same would be true if you had multiple cores and the threads were running genuinely in parallel. What's going on is that each of your threads is performing a "read modify write" operation (reading the value of x, then writing a new value). And this read modify write is non-atomic.

Comment: So the processes are not synchronized. Thread 2 reads the value of x to be 0 because the first thread didn't finish assigning the value of 1 to x hence the result would be 0. Did I understand it this time?

Comment: Yes exactly - the threads aren't synchronised and can therefore execute in any order, including interleaved :-)

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered, but maybe this is still useful:

Think of it as a sequence of atomic operations. The processor is doing one atomic operation at a time.

Here we have the following:

- Read x
- Write x
- Add 1
- Multiply 2

The following two sequences are guaranteed to happen in this order "within themselves":

- Read x, Add 1, Write x
- Read x, Multiply 2, Write x

However, if you are executing them in parallel, the time of execution of each atomic operation relative to any other atomic operation in **the other sequence** is random i.e. these two sequences interleave.

One of the possible order of execution will produce 0 which is given in the answer by Paul Butcher

Here is an illustration I found on the internet:

[image]

Each blue/purple block is one atomic operation, you can see how you can have different results based on the order of the blocks

To solve this problem you can use the keyword "**synchronized**"

My understanding is that if you mark two blocks of code (e.g. two methods) with synchronized within the same object then each block will own the lock of that object while being executed, so that the other block cannot be executed while the first hasn't finished yet. However, if you have two synchronised blocks in two different objects then they can execute in parallel.

Comment: This is a very detailed and in-depth answer. It's really helpful. +1

Comment: I'm sorry - perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm not aware of async making the sequence it's given into a single atomic operation. Indeed, if it did that then the answer 0 wouldn't be possible, would it, because interleaved operation wouldn't be possible?

Comment: @PaulButcher pffft, sorry I was thinking of "synchronized". I will fix my answer

Comment: @Bula please check the edit I made, I meant to say "synchronized"

Comment: Forgive me for the pedantry, but synchronized doesn't make the block of code it's given atomic either. What it does is claim the intrinsic lock associated with an object. So it will give you mutual exclusion against some other piece of code that claims the same intrinsic lock, but that's not the same thing as making it atomic.

Comment: @PaulButcher Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited that part. Do you think my explanation/understanding of it is correct?